# Is it possible to launch the default OpenXR runtime app dynamically?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I have a Unity game that I would like to make compatible with VR and desktop both in the same project.

I have a script that calls `XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.InitializeLoaderSync();` and `XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StartSubsystems();` when the app launches, as long as no `--disable-vr` argument was passed.

This script partially works as intended, and it launches into VR, but it requires the active OpenXR runtime (SteamVR, in my case) to be running, else it will fail to initialize.

I would like my app to automatically launch the player's default OpenXR runtime app, rather than having to have them launch it themselves, then launch the game afterwards.

The full script is as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.Management;
public class DynamicOpenXR : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const bool TestingDesktop = false;
    private string[] commandLineArgs;

    public static bool IsInVRMode = false; // This isn't yet used.
    
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSplashScreen)]
    void Awake()
    {
        commandLineArgs = TestingDesktop ? new[] { "Nexus.exe", "--disable-vr" } : Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        if (commandLineArgs.Contains("--disable-vr", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Debug.Log("Disable VR command line argument detected. Not enabling VR.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No VR disable argument detected. Initializing OpenXR.");
            StartCoroutine(InitializeOpenXR());
        }

        enabled = false;
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.activeLoader == null) return;
        
        Debug.Log("Shutting down OpenXR...");
        StartCoroutine(DeinitializeOpenXR());
    }

    IEnumerator DeinitializeOpenXR()
    {
        XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StopSubsystems();
        yield return null;
        
        XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.DeinitializeLoader();
    }

    IEnumerator InitializeOpenXR()
    {
        XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.InitializeLoaderSync();
        yield return null;

        while (!XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.isInitializationComplete)
            yield return null;

        XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StartSubsystems();
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!